# How i can send data between two windows for login using MVVM and autofac?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, autofac

I'm writing my first "real" MVVM application, and the first step the user will need to take is to provide login credentials.So I have the MainWindow holds a login page in the frame. I want when the user enters the username and password a new window opens with id and name of the user.So I have a main viewmodel and user viewmodel and I'm using autofac for dependency injection So here is my code.

viewmodel Code:

```
  public IEventAggregator _eventaggregator;
    private Func<IUserAccountViewModel> _useraccountviewmodelCreator;
    private IUserAccountViewModel _useraccountViewModel;
    public MainViewModel(INavigationViewModel navigationveiwmodel ,
        Func<IUserAccountViewModel> useraccountviewmodelCreator,IEventAggregator EventAggregator)
    {
        _useraccountviewmodelCreator = useraccountviewmodelCreator;
        _eventaggregator = EventAggregator;
        _eventaggregator.GetEvent<OpenDetailViewEvent>()
            .Subscribe(OnOpenDetailView);
        _eventaggregator.GetEvent<AfterUserSavedEvent>()
            .Subscribe(AfterUserSaved);
        NavigationViewModel = navigationveiwmodel;
        CreateNewUserCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnCreateNewUserExecute);
        LogInCommand = new DelegateCommand(onLoginExecute);
        _eventaggregator.GetEvent<OpenDetailViewEvent>().Subscribe(AfterLoginExecute);
    } 

private async void onLoginExecute()
    {
        UserAccountViewModel = _useraccountviewmodelCreator();
        await UserAccountViewModel.LoadAsyncByPassword(UserName, HashSomeText(Password));

    }

 private async void AfterLoginExecute(int? Userid)
    {
        UserAccountViewModel = _useraccountviewmodelCreator();
        await UserAccountViewModel.LoadAsync(Userid);
        CheckID = Userid.Value;
    }
 public INavigationViewModel NavigationViewModel { get; set; }
    public ICommand CreateNewUserCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand LogInCommand { get; set; }

public IUserAccountViewModel UserAccountViewModel
    {
        get { return _useraccountViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _useraccountViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and here is my user view model

```
 public async Task LoadAsyncByPassword(string UserName, string password)
    {
        var user = await _userRepository.GetAsyncByPassword(UserName, password);

        if(user!=null)
        {


            _eventaggregator.GetEvent<OpenDetailViewEvent>().Publish(user.Id);
        }
    }
```

here is my Bootstrapr code

```
 var bulider = new ContainerBuilder();

        bulider.RegisterType<EventAggregator>().As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance();
        bulider.RegisterType<BudGDbContext>().AsSelf();
        bulider.RegisterType<SplashScreen>().AsSelf();
        bulider.RegisterType<AuthorisationsWindow>().AsSelf();
        bulider.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
        bulider.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf();

        bulider.RegisterType<UserAccountViewModel>().As<IUserAccountViewModel>();
        bulider.RegisterType<NavigationViewModel>().As<INavigationViewModel>();
        bulider.RegisterType<LookupDataSeervice>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        bulider.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>();

        return bulider.Build();
```

So in this situation, i take the username and password and get the name and id but when I move to the mainwindow the id back to 0 so how i can move from AuthorisationsWindow to MainWindow with id and name of user?